# If two columns match change the third

Tags: awk, sed

File `1.txt`:

```
13002:1:3:6aw:4:g:Dw:S:5342:dsan
13003:5:3s:6s:4:g:D:S:3456:fdsa
13004:16:t3:6:4hh:g:D:S:5342:inef
```

File `2.txt`:

```
13002:6544
13003:5684
```

I need to replace the old data in column 9 of `1.txt` with new data from column 2 of `2.txt` if it exists. I think this can be done line by line as both files have the same column 1 field. This is a 3Gb file size. I have been playing about with awk but can't achieve the following.

I was trying the following:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;} {$9a[b[2]]}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

Expected result:

```
13002:1:3:6aw:4:g:Dw:S:6544:dsan
13003:5:3s:6s:4:g:D:S:5684:fdsa  
13004:16:t3:6:4hh:g:D:S:5342:inef
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Are both the files sorted in the same way regarding the first column?

Comment: Yes, both files are sorted in the same way regarding the first column. I was trying to use the line number of the current record with FNR. i was trying the following = awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;} {$9a[b[2]]}' 1.txt 2.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a couple of odd typos in your attempt.  You want to replace $9 with the value from the array if it is defined.  Also, you want to make sure Awk uses colon as separator both on input and output.

```
awk -F : 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}
    $1 in a {$9 = a[$1] } 1' 2.txt 1.txt
```

Notice how `2.txt` is first, so that `NR==FNR` is true when you are reading this file, but not when you start reading `1.txt`.  The `next` in the first block prevents Awk from executing the second condition while you are reading the first file.  And the final `1` is a shorthand for an unconditional `print` which of course will be executed for every line in the second file, regardless of whether you replaced anything.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, I was quite far off from your example. It worked for me! Thanks again.